# Mute all participants except host - Tokbox

Tags: javascript, tokbox

**Using Tokbox javascript SDK and C# SDK for establishing video calls.**

As a Host I want to have the ability to mute all other participants with a single click, and that the mute will occur for other participants as well within the meeting so that I am able to maintain control of the meeting and ensure that I am the only being heard and uninterrupted within the meeting.

For this requirement, I am not able to find any useful documentation links and got stuck with this for a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

We recently offered "mute all" and "mute session" functionality as a beta option via the REST API. The feature is currently available as a beta release in our Python implementation for the server side, which you can take a look at [here](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Python-SDK/blob/8422a2dc6e6430118d45ada7ac736eef762a87e2/opentok/opentok.py#L1374), and is available in 2.20.0 of the [JS SDK](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/release-notes.html). This lets a moderator mute any stream currently connected, but it does not currently allow you to force-mute on entry, and participants can still unmute themselves.

We are adding the above functionality but it is not available at the moment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @dragonmantank.

Comment: Hi @dragonmantank, Can we also have the option for unmuting all participants in one button click. Also can we have the option for unmuting one specific participant?